# I have a problem I have one website but two webhooks endpoints

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have a problem I have one website but two webhooks endpoints
when call one endpoint the other also call and this not right I don't why that happend

every webhooks has STRIPE_SECRET

ex:
https://website.com/webhooks/stripe 
https://website.com/extensions/stripe

there both use checkout.session.completed

but every endpoint have different route and different controller

route one

```
Route::post('/rentals/purchase/{plan}', RentalCheckoutController::class)->name('rentals.checkout')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/rentals/purchase/success', RentalCheckoutSuccessController::class)->name('rentals.success')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/webhooks/stripe',StripeWebhookController::class);
```

route two

```
Route::post('/rentals/purchase/extension/{rental}',[RentalExtensionCheckoutController::class,'index'])->name('rentals.extension.checkout')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/rentals/purchase/extension/success', RentalExtensionSuccessController::class)->name('rentals.extension.success')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/extensions/stripe',StripeWebhookExtensionController::class);
```

this is the handleCheckoutSessionCompleted for one controller

```
protected function handleCheckoutSessionCompleted(array $payload)
    {
        $paymentStatus = data_get($payload, 'data.object.payment_status', null);
        $priceInCents = $payload['data']['object']['amount_subtotal'];
        $priceInEur = $priceInCents / 100;

        // Log::info($payload);

        $session_id = $payload['data']['object']['id'];
        $metadata = $payload['data']['object']['metadata'];
        $rental_uuid = $metadata['rental_uuid'];
    
        $rental = Rental::where('uuid', $rental_uuid)->first();
    
        if ($rental) {
            // Update the end_time
            $newEndTime = Carbon::parse($metadata['end_time']);
            $rental->end_time = $newEndTime;
            $rental->save();
    
            // Create a new additional_rentals record
            AdditionalRental::create([
                'user_id' => $rental->user_id,
                'rental_uuid' => $rental->uuid,
                'end_time' => $newEndTime,
                'price' => $priceInEur, 
                'datetime' => now(),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the middlerware for one of them

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stripe\WebhookSignature;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class VerifyStripeWebhookExtensionSecret
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {

        $endpoint_secret = env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET2');


            try {
                WebhookSignature::verifyHeader(
                    $request->getContent(),
                    $request->header('Stripe-signature'),
                    $endpoint_secret



                );
             
            } catch (SignatureVerificationException $exception) {
                // Invalid payload
                throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($exception->getMessage(),$exception);
            }


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple webhook endpoints on the same account that listen to the same event types, and an event of that type occurs on your Stripe account, all endpoints will be sent that event.